# How can I check if an anonymous function has been called with NSubstitute?

Tags: c#, func, nsubstitute

I want to check if an anonymous function has been called with NSubstitute. A method in a class I have takes a `Func<>` parameter, and I want to make sure this parameter is called (or not called). I have tried the following, but it does not seem to work:

```
var spy = Substitute.For<Func<string, int>>();
MyClass.DoSomething(spy);
spy.Invoke(Arg.Any<string>()).Received();
```

This however throws an exception:

```
NSubstitute.Exceptions.NullSubstituteReferenceException : NSubstitute extension methods like .Received can only be called on objects created using Substitute.For<T>() and related methods.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try replacing

```
spy.Invoke(Arg.Any<string>()).Received();
```

with

```
spy.Received().Invoke(Arg.Any<string>());
```

There's no difference if your production code calls the func via `spy.Invoke()` or via `spy()`. But the test won't succeed, if your code calls `BeginInvoke`. But I think that shouldn't be a problem, because you should know in advance if a test for `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` is needed.

Comment: Is there a way to check it independently of how the spy is called? As in, it could have been called using BeginInvoke, which I don't think this test would pass on?